# Error in view page source

Tags: html, dom

When web page loads first on browser tab then page load itself properly but we "right click->View Page Source" on it then we saw actual page source correctly but when we "right click->Inspect element" then goto "Sources" tab then html dom is not shown at very first time but when refresh the same then view the html dom at the same time.
I don't know what the issue is and how to resolve it.Help me and your help is very appreciable for me

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. Potentially your issue is coming about because 'View Source' and 'Inspect Element' are two different things. View Source will show you the source HTML that was delivered to the Browser. Inspect Element will show this, as well as anything that has been altered by JavaScript, any inline styles etc as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro don't worry. There's nothing wrong in your site or whatever site you have inspected on. It's the google chrome' updated feature to hide html source. When you click on the source link situated in left nav bar, you will get the source code. You don't need to refresh it. 
And also view source is a static source, returned from server, while inspect element is a dynamic console, i.e, it changes your layout according to user's changes.